# Ruby returning statement

Tags: ruby

I am trying to return a `UserStubPresenter` (a nested JSON presenter) corresponding to the user who received the email, assuming they are still present in the system. If they are no longer present, it should just be `nil`.

And this is what I have so far for ruby. Please explain this syntax and help me with the return statement in details.

```
return UserStubPresenter.new @object.recipient if @options[:shallow].to_bool
```

Comment: If `@options[:shallow].to_bool` is a truty value then `UserStubPresenter.new @object.recipient` is returned.

Comment: what if `@options[:shallow].to_bool` returns false?

Comment: How can I know why `@options[:shallow].to_bool` returns false?

Comment: Maybe you can add more code context?

Comment: if `@options[:shallow].to_bool` is `false` or `nil` then the next instruction is executed. If it is reached end of method/function then it returns `nil` implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

There are two important pieces to understand. First, Ruby reads this line like this:

```
return(UserStubPresenter.new(@object.recipient)) if @options[:shallow].to_bool
```

And it evaluates the `if` condition first. That means – as zeitnot already wrote – if `@options[:shallow].to_bool` is truthy then `UserStubPresenter.new(@object.recipient)` is evaluated and returned.

Seconds, if you don’t return explicitly, then Ruby will return the return value of the last evaluated statement. Your example is a shorter version of

```
if @options[:shallow].to_bool
  return UserStubPresenter.new @object.recipient
else
end
```

The last expression is the empty else path, therefore, your that *line* would return `nil` – no explicit `return nil` needed.

And assuming that that line is the last line of a method then you do not need the `return` at all.